# Como utilizar o to_number no PostgreSQL com número no formato brasileiro

Tags: postgresql

Tenho uma coluna do tipo text '1534,99', ou seja com o número no formato em português. Como faço para usar a função `to_number` nesse caso?

`SELECT TO_NUMBER('1534,99','9999999D99')` deveria funcionar se fosse o "." no lugar da ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **D** do format '9999999D99' representa o ponto decimal e este se baseia no locale do seu banco. o PostgreSQL usa o ponto como separador decimal devido ao padrão americano.

Uma possibilidade sem mudar o locale é usar a Funcção **REPLACE**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REPLACE('1534,99', ',','.'),'9999999D99');
```

Fontes: 
[lc_numeric](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-LC-NUMERIC)
[padrões de formatação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-NUMERIC-TABLE)